# Spring AOP: Interceptor not working

Tags: java, spring, aop, spring-aop, aspect

The annotation:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ElementType.METHOD})
public @interface DeadlockRetry {


}
```

The Interceptor:

```
public class DeadlockRetryMethodInterceptor implements MethodInterceptor
{

    @Override
    public Object invoke(MethodInvocation invocation) throws Throwable
    {
        System.err.println("I've been Intercepted!");
        return invocation.proceed();
    }
}
```

The Intercepted Class:

```
public class Intercepted {


    @DeadlockRetry
    public void interceptMe()
    {
        System.err.println("Above here should be a message I've been Intercepted!");
    }
}
```

The Main startpoint:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        //Function that loads the spring-context.xml
        SpringContext.init();

        Intercepted intercepted = new Intercepted();
        intercepted.interceptMe();
    }
}
```

The spring-context.xml:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
     classpath:/org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
     classpath:/org/springframework/transaction/config/spring-tx-3.2.xsd
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
     classpath:/org/springframework/aop/config/spring-aop-3.2.xsd
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
     classpath:/org/springframework/context/config/spring-context-3.2.xsd">


    <aop:aspectj-autoproxy />



    <context:annotation-config/>

    <bean id="deadlockRetryAdvice" class="com.metaregistrar.hibernate.DeadlockRetryMethodInterceptor"/>



    <bean id="deadlockPointcutAdvisor" class="org.springframework.aop.support.DefaultPointcutAdvisor">
        <property name="advice" ref="deadlockRetryAdvice"/>
        <property name="pointcut" ref="deadlockRetryPointcut"/>
    </bean>


    <bean name="deadlockRetryPointcut" class="org.springframework.aop.support.annotation.AnnotationMatchingPointcut">
        <constructor-arg index="0" value="com.metaregistrar.hibernate.DeadlockRetry"/>
        <constructor-arg index="1" value="com.metaregistrar.hibernate.DeadlockRetry"/>
    </bean>



</beans>
```

The Stderr result:

Above here should be a message I've been Intercepted!

The expected Stderr result:

I've been Intercepted!
Above here should be a message I've been Intercepted!

What am I doing wrong? I've been at this problem for the whole day now and It's getting pretty annoying...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spring AOP only works for spring beans.  You should define the intercepted object as a bean in the spring config file, get it from the context and invoke method on it.

This is the part that is not correct.

```
Intercepted intercepted = new Intercepted();
intercepted.interceptMe();
```

Add this to the xml file

And then retreive the instance from the spring ctx

```
ApplicationContext ctx = // create context using the config file

intercepted = ctx.getBean("intercepted",Intercepted.class);

intercepted.interceptMe();
```

Comment: I already moved away from Spring AOP to AspectJ's @Aspect. After figuring I need to define nearly every class as a bean into the spring context. Which I feel is kinda unneeded.

But hey, thanks for the solution. This is the answer to this problem. But not entirely what I was seeking.

Comment: Upvote for this answer..  and after proofing this understanding : a slight clarification.  It isn't "just defined as a Bean".    It has to be (somewhere) PULLED from the IoC context "as a bean".    So something in applicationContext.xml OR as a @Configuration/@Bean will not get "aspected".  It has to be defined AND pulled from the IoC in some form or fashion.